# Determine gateway and other information without an IP

Tags: networking

I have a server connected to a network. I'm logged into this server via console. The server was configured for a static IP, but this server used to live on a different vlan so the static IP information is incorrect. This network does not use DHCP. How do I:

1. Pick an unused IP on whatever subnet this vlan uses?
2. Determine the subnet mask?
3. Determine the "network" address?
4. Determine the gateway?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`arp -an` will help, as will broadcast `ping` to the subnet.

Answer (score -1):

Find the MAC address of the server in the switch and look for the port configuration.  If you are able to get this (and I know this may be a big 'if') then look for other devices on the same VLAN and note their IP information.